# How to add columns on the online sprint board

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, tfs-process-template, scrumboard

I'm trying to understand how to add columns on the web version of TFS for my latest sprint but can't find the options to do so.

Using the default model (To do, In progress, done) does not capture the complexity and need for my team so I need an extra column but do not know how to add it.

If someone could give me pointers on the web version of TFS that would be great.

Comment: Welcome! I switched a few tasks as the question wasn't as much about agile project management, but about the tool configuration

Answer (score 1):

The sprint board can't be customized through the UI a more complex sequence of steps is required, this involves exporting a couple of XML files, editing them end importing them back in:

- Export the task WIT from TFS using `witadmin exportwitd`
- Add the required State(s)
- Add the required State transition(s)
- Export the processconfig using `witadmin exportprocessconfig`
- Update the task board configuration to add the new state(s)
- Import the task WIT using `witadmin importwitd`
- Import the processconfig using `witadmin importprocessconfig`

See:

- [Modify workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/add-modify-wit?view=vsts#modify-workflow)
- [Add work item types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/add-wits-to-backlogs-and-boards?view=vsts)

This is best performed on a (temporary) test Team project collection to finetine the process, you can then import the tested configuration into the existing project.

Comment: Jesse, does this mean that making this change with witadmin will affect all Backlog items while the user is in the online sprint board? We're working with TFS 2015. We'd like this change to only 1 TFS Team project.

Comment: In TFS 2015 all the way to 2019 these changes will affect one team project at a time.